# configure: error: in `/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/

Tags: android, linux, kivy

Hello evryone i try to compiling  my first program so . i hoop you guys can help me to solve this one. after installing a lot of packages on my kali linux and excuting this command buildozer -v android debug. i get the some errors i try to install al last version of pip pyhton en etc but i stuck here>

```
 configure: error: in `/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1256, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 685, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 104, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 163, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 30, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./configure'),
  File "/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/kingofblack/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/kingofblack/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kingofblack/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77: 

  RAN: /home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure --host=aarch64-linux-android --prefix=/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking target system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-android
checking for gsed... sed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for aarch64-linux-android-strip... /home/kingofblack/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make -j4 sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make -j4 supports nested variables... yes
checking for aarch64-linux-android-gcc... /home/kingofblack/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/kingofblack/buildozer/pythonTest/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']                                                                                

# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Are you running Kali over WSL?

If so, [check on this](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users?tab=readme-ov-file#c-compiler-cannot-create-executables)